# Show message before deleting more than 50 entities of any layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

A user has already wiped out all entities on a layer several times. Glad that I had backups.

I want to develop a QGIS macro that alerts the user before deleting more than 50 entities at once.

After several hours trying things I've come with a working prompt message:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import *
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog


def openProject():
    reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(iface.mainWindow(),'CAUTION!!'
            ,
            'You are going to delete more than 50 entities. Are you really sure to proceed?'
            , QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
    if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Yes')
    else:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('No')

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```

But I am having a hard time developing the rest.

I need to listen to the pencil (edit layer) button event for any layer and add this prompt before saving the deleted entitites if the count of deleted entities to save is >50.

I think I need to use [Signals and Slots](https://gis-ops.com/qgis-3-plugin-tutorial-pyqt-signal-slot-explained/) and connect to some event before data is saved but how do I approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trial and error I have found the code that does what I want:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import *
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog


def openProject():

    def logBeforeCommitChanges():
        layer = iface.activeLayer()
        if layer.editBuffer():
            ids = layer.editBuffer().deletedFeatureIds()
            if len(ids) > 50:
                reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(iface.mainWindow(),
                        'WARNING!!',
                        'You are going to delete more than 50 features at a time. Are you sure to proceed??'
                        , QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
                        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
                if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                    pass
                else:
                    layer.editBuffer().rollBack()
    
    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
    for mylayer in layers:
        if hasattr(mylayer, 'fields'):
            mylayer.beforeCommitChanges.connect(logBeforeCommitChanges)


def saveProject():
    pass


def closeProject():
    pass
```

Comment: What if the user adds a layer afterwards?